# After site transfer I'm still getting redirected to the old site (WordPress)

Tags: urls, migration

I have transfered my WordPress theme on another domain doing these steps:

1. I have used a backup plugin and backed up database
2. Transfered wp-content folder to the new site
3. Uploaded the database to a new host
4. Changed `siteurl` in `wp-options` to a new one

But I'm still getting redirected on the old URL pressing on the header.

In `header.php` the PHP echo `home_url();` could be changed, so I'll be redirected on the new URL but I'm not sure that this is the solution.

Would be glad to hear from you what have I done wrong.

Comment: You need to run a full find and replace on the database, the old site url is stored in MANY more places than that single option row.  Search this site, there's a million guides/tools/scripts to do it for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution for this:

> Settings » General » Change URL address

I changed my site URL to new and it's working just fine.